# JacORB: changing prefix and suffix

Tags: ant, corba, idl, jacorb

I would like to change package **prefix and suffix** in my ant build while generating java from idl. This has to be generic solution! The idea goes like that:

I have idl files (ONE.idl, TWO.idl) with namespace **ONE_cb** in first and **TWO_cb** in second (as _cb suffix is required for c++ compatibility). TWO_cb has atributes from ONE_cb, ONE_cb has only basic types. I want to change that to packages going like **com.example.ONE** and **com.example.TWO**.

I'm using JacORB 3.6. and I don't know how to do it.
My code looks like that:

```
<target name="idlj-generate">
<idl2java
   srcdir="${psm.dir}/${project}/"
   destdir="${build.generated.dir}"
   includepath="${psm.dir}"
   all="true">
      <define key="__JACORB_GENERATE__"/>
      <i2jpackage names=":com.example"/>
      <i2jpackage names="_cb:"/>
</idl2java>
</target>
```

It doesn't work. As I stated before it has to be generic solution. adding

```
<i2jpackage names="TWO_cb:TWO"/> //option 2
<i2jpackage names="ONE_cb:ONE"/> //option 2b
```

Is not acceptable

Thank you for Your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For various research I concluded that generic solution is immpossible.
Only way to perform changing prefix and suffix the same time is to explicite set all included names.

Comment: If you could provide a full test case in the JacORB Bugzilla I could look into it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have something like

```
module ONE_cb
{
...
}
```

but you want it to be

```
com.example.ONE { ... }
```

This is feasible with i2jpackage e.g.

```
idl -forceOverwrite -d /tmp/generated -i2jpackage ONE_cb:com.example.ONE myfile.idl
```

The problem you have is that you are compiling both files at once. Remove the "all" and try compiling them in two phases.

If you are using Maven I would also recommend trying org.codehaus.mojo:idlj-maven-plugin as you can do multiple executions very easily with that.

To use multiple i2jpackage I got it working with

```
idl -forceOverwrite -d /tmp/generated -all -i2jpackagefile /tmp/file antBugJac608-2.idl
```

(where antBugJac608-2 #includes antBugJac608).

Comment: That doesn't help me. First of all I'm not using maven. Secondly as I stated twice: I want generic solution - changing names explicite is obvious.  
  
Third and most important thing: compiling in two phases will generate ONE properly (because it has only basic types) but compiling TWO without ONE will cause error as TWO has attributes from ONE, i.e.       *ONE_cb::structA a;* and firstly generated file is no longer ONE_cb, but com.example.ONE

Comment: I've edited my answer to include multiple i2jpackage. I believe the Ant task also supports i2jpackagefile (file=xxx) so you could try that.

Comment: Thank You for your time - at this and previous question - but this time it didn't help me:
1. I found out generic solution is immposible in jacORB. I need to know all names and change them via i2jpackage.  
2. As I said previously - removing "all" flag won't compile my source files,  as every lies in different folder and generates to different folder.  
  
Netherless thank You for your time

Comment: In my modified comment (see the command at the bottom ) I kept the 'all' flag